# access viewModel properties

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is it possible to access viewModel properties at any time in any script on the page? In the model below I want to use currModel as a place to store a certain flag, can I do this without binding it to something in DOM? Thx for any help.

```
function viewModel(result,currentTheme) {
    var self = this;
    self.isBlankForm = !(result.payload.isBlankForm);
    self.snapEdit = result.payload.emailText;
    self.snapEditSuccess = result.payload.successBody;
    self.isMeNotified = result.payload.isMeNotified;
    self.isEmailSentToUser = result.payload.isEmailSentToUser;
    self.fromEmailBox = result.payload.fromUserEmail;
    self.subjectEmailBox = result.payload.emailSubject;
    self.themeNames = ko.observableArray(result.payload.themeList);
    self.themeChoice = ko.observable(self.themeNames.find("id", currentTheme));
    self.bgColor = result.payload.bgColor;
    self.frmColor = result.payload.frmColor;
    self.txtColor = result.payload.txtColor;
    self.btnColor = result.payload.btnColor;
    self.btnTxtColor = result.payload.btnTxtColor;
    self.currModel = ko.observable();
}
```

Comment: Sure, just store your VM in a variable. For example: `var myVM = new viewModel(); ko.applyBindings(myVM);`. Now you can access `myVM.currModel();` whenever you need it.

Comment: Ah, nice one! Should have been an answer though :D

Comment: I've posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just store your VM in a variable.

For example:

```
var myVM = new viewModel(); 
ko.applyBindings(myVM);
```

Now you can access `myVM.currModel()` whenever you need it.